# Align button on bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I've added a button on the carousel item. some of them align nicely but there are some that went off a bit. How do i align them all? thanks. using bootstrap 3.3.7

[image]

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data- 
interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
      <img src="item/beras.png" class="img-responsive">
      <p>Beras</p>
      <button class="btn default">Donate</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is because of different image size. You just have to add image inside `div` and giving div a constant height. Most probably, this will solve the problem.

Comment: well that worked easily. thanks @HamidR.

Comment: Happy to help you @Grey

Comment: @HamidR. while it was a simple response, please add an answer instead of a comment. Refer to the section **When _shouldn't_ I comment?** on [Comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).